# How can I build and link Lua core and few Lua modules in one .exe file

Tags: build, lua, static-linking

I need to make portable application, that will run on Windows, Linux, MacOS and no install required. It must be one executable file and no other library files (.dll, .so ...). I will use ANSI C and recompile project for each platform. I want to use Lua scripts, so must embed Lua interpreter in my code. I need network and some other modules to write but i now that Lua already have modules for that purpose, so I will use them instead writing my own.
How can I link all that together, Lua interpreter, Lua modules (LuaSocks i.e.) in one executable file that will load .lua script. Lua has "require" system that expects .dll to find, so I wondering what I should do, is it enough just to call functions without "require" statement.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You most certainly *can* do that (and it is not wrong!), although it is not trivial. The Lua core is made for embedding, to the point that you can just include the Lua sources into your own project and it *"just works"* :).

The deal is slightly different with modules - not many of them are suited for direct embedding. For example, this has been tried successfully for [LuaSocket](http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2005-10/msg00269.html) before and also [asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2197144/how-could-i-embedded-socket-in-lua-internally-just-like-oslib-debuglib). The basic idea is to embed the sources of MODULE  to your project and insert the `luaopen_MODULE` function into `package.preload['MODULE']`, so that `require` can pick it up later.

One way to go is to look at sources of projects that already embed Lua and other libraries, like [LÖVE](http://love2d.org/), [MurgaLua](http://www.murga-projects.com/murgaLua/murgaLua.html) and [Scrupp](http://scrupp.sourceforge.net/).

If the goal of not having a single executable with no external libraries turns out not achievable, you can loosen up a bit and go for *portable* application - an application that carries all it's dependencies with it, in a single directory, independent of the system. This is what [LuaDist](http://luadist.org/) was designed for - you use it similar to LuaRocks to install Lua packages. The difference is that these packages can be installed/deployed into a separate directory, where all necessary dependencies are installed too. This directory (a "dist") is fully independent, meaning you can move it somewhere else and it will still work.

Also, I dislike the idea of an application that requires *installation* (because it puts files all around my system) - *uninstallation* should be just removal of a directory :)

Comment: Again, you need a lua interpreter (or JIT compiler) to use the lua bytecode provided with the application.

Comment: Yes, that is what I said in the first paragraph - you can include the whole compiler and interpreter into your project. That is Lua - compiled 200KB of pure magic :)

Comment: Hm, think I should develop my app with external modules, and later try to embed everything in single binary. Recompiling and embedding Lua core is not problem, just modules, that is a bit of problem.

Comment: Thanks for the link to LuaDist!  I note they have a project that will bundle a single Lua file - not quite the question, but could be extended.  https://github.com/LuaDist/srlua

Answer (score 0):

I believe you cannot do that (and I think it is wrong to do that). An executable is operating system and machine specific (on some systems like MacOSX, there are [fat binary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fat_binary) executables, which are a mix of various machine specific variants for the *same* operating system.).

The only way to have a system & machine "independent" program is essentially to target it to some single *common* "virtual machine" (in the broadest sense). In your case this VM is the Lua VM (it could be the Java VM for others, etc.). But you have to suppose that your user have it, or to provide one which is machine & system specific.

And I would personally dislike the idea of an application which is not installable (because it is then not easily *uninstallable*).

Comment: An application which is not installed shouldn't need to be uninstalled. It should be removable by simple deleting the executable; or, at most, if it creates some files in its own, empty directory, by removing this directory. *Or*, the application itself could provide its own "uninstallation".

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear. I will use ANSI C and recompile project for each platform. Just want to have same source.

Comment: That should be very simple. What did you try? Your application could be a set of C files (`*.c` & `*.h`) and a set of Lua files (`*.lua`). You need a README (or perhaps a Makefile) explaining how it should be built and used. Put all that in a directory. Distribute the tar ball or the .zip archive.